# Is there a way to remove stationery from incoming mail messages in outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Is there a way to remove stationery from incoming mail messages in outlook 2007? (such as background colours and background images)

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you  http://adam.rosi-kessel.org/weblog/2008/01/26/windows-outlook-2003-tip-vba-macro-to-remove-stationery-from-email-message